# Trying to add SAM, country, language and proxyaddress from CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

So I have CSV file with all these values firstname, lastname, SAM, email, department, OU, country, language and proxyaddress.

I can successfully create users but don't know how to add most importantly SAM and proxyaddress, but also don't know how I would add department, country and language into each users attributes, these other values are less important.

What I've tried:

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity $name -EmailAddresses @{add= $proxy}

Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like "*"' -SearchBase $ou -Properties * | % {Set-ADUser $_ -add @{proxyAddresses=$proxy}}

Add-ADGroupMember -Identity groupname
```

Here is the code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$securedPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "" -AsPlainText -Force

$userlist = Import-Csv "C:\users.csv"

ForEach ($row in $userlist) {
    $fname = $row.'givenName'
    $lname = $row.'Lastname'
    $sam = $row.'SAM'
    $mail = $row.'mail'
    $department = $row.'Department'
    $ou = $row.'OU'
    $country = $row.'Country'
    $lang = $row.'Preferredlanguage'
    $proxy = $row.'Proxy'

    $name = $fname + $lname
    $proxy = $row.'Proxy' -split ';'

    New-ADUser -Name "$fname $lname" -GivenName $fname -Surname $lname -UserPrincipalName "$mail" -Path $ou -AccountPassword $securedPassword -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -EmailAddress $mail
```

Error when trying to include SAM into New-ADUser:

```
New-ADUser : The name provided is not a properly formed account name
At C:\test.ps1:28 char:5
+     New-ADUser -sAMAccountName $sam -Name "$fname $lname" -GivenName  ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=Fay,OU=Us...,DC=com:String) [New-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:1315,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

Comment: It would help if you would provide a few lines from the CSV file, because in your code you use different properties than the fields you name in the question. Also, the code would improve dramatically when you would use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) on a cmdlet that uses so many parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your CSV file I can't say for sure, but it sounds like your CSV has a value that is not valid as a `sAMAccountName`. There are rules for what it can be, which are listed in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-samaccountname):

> This attribute must be 20 characters or less to support earlier clients, and cannot contain any of these characters:
>
> - "/ \ [ ] : ; | = , + * ? < >

Comment: The SAM field in the CSV is: AD\firstname.lastname
So it should only be firstname.lastname? And then the AD\ part gets automatically added?

Comment: Also, the file is currently formatted with SMTP: email@email.com. Is it unnessecary to include the SMTP: part?

Comment: Correct: you don't include the domain in the `sAMAccountName` attribute.

Comment: For the email address: if you're adding it to the `mail` attribute, then there is no `smtp:` prefix. If you're putting it in `proxyAddresses`, then you do.